# How to store db credentials for use on either heroku or development when using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a db.js file in my node app which contains the credentials for the heroku database i'm using and the local database I'm using.

I want to a.stop having to manually comment out the credentials, as well as the ability to be able for the app to know when it's running on heroku (and therefore use the heroku credentials) Also i'm worried about security, I know I can just omit storing the db.js file from my github repo, but I'm not sure what the best practice for this is.

```
db.js file

var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = {

  development: {
    conn : mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test1'

    })
  },

  // heroku credentials

  production: {
    conn : mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'test.net',
      user: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      database: 'heroku'
    })

  }

}




module.exports = conn;
```

How i'm calling it in my code

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var conn = require('./db')[env];
```

and then using it like

```
 let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
```

Which is giving me the following error

```
conn.query is not a function
```

Comment: A `.env` file for local. Heroku's config vars work the same way. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/nodejs-custom-env-files-in-your-apps-fa7b3e67abe1

Answer (score 0):

You can set your env variables with Heroku cli

Exemple for your SQL user and password

```
$ heroku config:set SQL_PASSWORD=XXX
$ heroku config:set SQL_USER=John
```

And use it

```
production: {
    conn : mysql.createConnection({
    ...
    password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
    user: process.env.SQL_USER,
    database: 'heroku'
})
```

Good to know: Heroku set automatically NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION

Look at this documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars